# "Cannot create instance of WindowsPage"

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I created a Xamarin.Forms cross-platform application template.
Now I am getting "Cannot create instance of WindowsPage" error in the UWP project.
Note: I have not made any changes to the template.
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp1Jn.jpg)

Comment: Can you please check the stacktrace.

Comment: Yeah, I have added a screenshot of the stacktrace. Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the error does not prevent the project from compiling and only appears if the MainPage.xaml file is open in the editor. So I would suggest that you close that file prior to building your solution and the error will go away.

Anyway, I hope that helps.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Pretty sad (for UWP+Xamarin) this "comment" helped me. So it's actually the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

It just does that at times. You need to deploy your application once. Thereafter, the error should not come again. Atleast, thats how it worked for me.