# How to fix error "Cannot create an instance of WindowsPage" in the XAML Desinger in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

For starters, I have seen the other questions that are exact copies, but none of those, have a good enough answer.

After creating a new Xamarin Shared Project in Visual Studio, I noticed that the Designer in the UWP project didn't work. It just gave this exception and stacktrace:

```
Exception: Cannot create an instance of "WindowsPage". 
 Stacktrace: 
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.InstanceBuilderOperations.InstantiateType(Type type, Boolean supportInternal)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.InstantiateTargetType(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.InstanceBuilders.FrameworkElementInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.InstanceBuilders.UserControlInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNodeManager.CreateInstance(IInstanceBuilder builder, ViewNode viewNode)
```

It has an Inner exception which i will upload if needed, but my problem is contrary the answers i see, where people say there is no functional designer for XAML in Xamarin.Forms, it had worked once in a former project that i was just using to sharpen my skills.

I have tried all sorts of stuff and nothing seems to work. Please help me.

Comment: it seemed to be error of visual studio 2015, just ignore it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929863/cannot-create-instance-of-windowspage

Comment: To ignore is a way to build the application but no solution. VisualStudio has a reason to show the error. In most cases the designer has custom controls which uses codebehind instances which are `null` while working in design mode. This needs to be fixed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesignmode?view=netframework-4.8